# How to fix Video tearing with KDE and ati drivers?

Tags: 12.04, ati, kde, tearing, kwin

I have Ubuntu 12.04.02 x64 and KDE 4.10.00.
I'm having a little video tearing while playing ANY video (HD mkv, avi, etc.).

- it happens with vlc latest version and with default Ubuntu video player and also with other players like kmplayer.
- I have some effects enabled and I use: OpenGL, Raster, Shaders: OpenGL 2 and vertical sync.
- I have ATI MSI R6870 hawk with latest `fglrx` video card driver AMD Catalyst™ 13.1 Proprietary Linux Display Driver
- My pc hardware are:
  **CPU:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 Sandy Bridge
  **Motherboard:** Asus P8P67 PRO
  **Display:** full hd display (DVI)
- `glxinfo` says `direct rendering: yes`
- No problem with Windows 7.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMD Catalyst software has an option to reduce tearing.

Open a terminal and type `kdesudo amdcccle`, then find the section for reducing tearing and check the option.

Additionally, I should mention that I had some tearing issues with VLC and Totem a while ago (before the 13.1 driver was released), but using smplayer instead of VLC dramatically improved my video playback. If the Catalyst option doesn't work for you, give smplayer a try and see if that helps.

Comment: wow, it just solved my problem. The ati option works great so even vlc doesn't make tearing. And smplayer is even better. thanks
Btw does this ati option makes my video card work more?